# How to use where condition in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel eloquent. I have fetched data from two table using eloquent. 
I have `post` table and `chat` table. For `post` table I have model `Post.php` and for `chat` table I have model `Chat.php`. Here is the the eloquent relation I have created to fetch chat for individual post for a user.

in `Post.php`

```
public function TeamMessage()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Chat','post_id');
}
```

And in `Chat.php`

```
public function ChatRelation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

it is working perfect. But this relation fetch all messages for a specific post. I want to fetch all unread message from `chat` table. I have a column named `unread` in `chat` table. 
Now my question is how I can fetch only `unread` message for a specific post.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers all work, they either depend on scopes (which are very useful in many circumstances) or on you having already instantiated an instance of `$post`, which doesn't let you eager load multiple posts with their messages.

The dynamic solution is this, which will let you fetch either 1 or more posts and eager load their messages with subquery:

```
$posts = Post::with(['TeamMessage' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('unread', true); // This part applies to the TeamMessage query
}])->get();
```

[See in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Edit:

If you, however, want to filter the posts, to only show those that have unread messages, you need to use `whereHas` instead of `with`:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas(['TeamMessage' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('unread', true); // This part applies to the TeamMessage query
}])->get();
```

[More in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

You can also chain `whereHas(...)` with `with(...)`.

Comment: I have tried it in my controller. It fetch all post from post table only. I have done dd(). it shows all post and also shows 
` #relations: array:1 [▼
        "TeamMessage" => Collection {#372 …1}
      ]`

Comment: Yeah and the TeamMessages should be filtered only to those that are unread. Do you need to filter the posts to only those that have unread messages?

Comment: yes. you are correct.And your answer is working. But I want more filtering. Like if i created 5 post, then I just want to fetch my created post and their unread messages. Please help.

Comment: @Fokrule Use `whereHas` instead. See my edit for an example

Answer (score 0):

For querying relationships, you have to call them as functions instead of properties, like this:

```
$unreadPosts = $post->TeamMessage()->where('unread', true)->get();
```

For more information on this you can take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Comment: i have tried this code in my controller. it says undefined variable $post

Comment: Well, `$post` will be your instance of the `Post` class.

Comment: Sorry, I din't understand properly. Sorry for my weakness.  Can you please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a local scope on your model, information on local scopes can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes

```
 public function scopeUnread($query)
{
    return $query->where('unread', 1);
}
```

Then in your controller/view

```
$unread = $yourmodel->unread()
```

Comment: i have tried this code in my controller. it says undefined variable $yourmodel. I have used my model name here

Comment: It was an example. Of course $yourmodel is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First I would change your relation names to the name of the entity in lower case:

in Post.php

```
public function chats()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chat','post_id');
}
```

And in Chat.php

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}

public function scopeUnread($query)
{
    return $query->where('unread', 1);
}
```

Then you can use

```
$post->chats()->unread()->get();
```

Comment: i have tried this code in my controller. it says undefined variable $post